# Is there a way to create certificates in Kubernetes using the PHP library?

Tags: php, kubernetes, azure-aks

I need to create the certificates without using `kubectl` commands, but with the [Kubernetes PHP Client library](https://github.com/allansun/kubernetes-php-client). I want these certificates to be created automatically when I am creating the cluster. Is there a way to do that?
Sorry if the question is ambiguous, I am new to Kubernetes.

Comment: are you sure you are using kubectl to create certificates? there's no such option in kubectl i know of. you may want to share what kubectl commands you are trying to move to api calls.

Comment: I am talking about the process described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/), where you create a Certificate Signing Request that has to be manually approved. @MarkusDresch

Comment: seems like off-topic, because you can create certificates without the Kubernetes at all